# How to improve query and document similarity measure python TFIDF, BM25 precision, recall

Tags: python, precision, information-retrieval, tf-idf, precision-recall

I tried to calculate TF-IDF for both query and documents, and using COS distance to rank the result and get the top50 similar documents. 
Similarly, I calculate BM25 score and rank the highest BM25 score as No.1, and get the top50 similar documents.

However, for both TF-IDF and BM25 the results are not good.

(the dataset is label. size of the testing dataset is 1400 document):

```
For example in the testing dataset judgment

the queryID=1 
the relevant document ID is : 19.txt, 25.txt, 35.txt, 38.txt,133.txt,45.txt
```

......................................

after input the queryID=1 in the search system i create. It retrieved 365 documents from total 1400 documents.

So I used the IT-IDF ranking for queryID=1, 365 documents

```
the system might only return the  relevant document ID: 38.txt
```

similarly, I used BM25 ranking for queryID=1, 365 documents

```
 the system might only return the  relevant document ID: 19.txt
```

By checking the 365 documents manually, in the 365 documents: it actually consists the  relevant document ID: 19.txt, 25.txt, 35.txt, 38.txt, 45.txt, and the other non-relevant document ID.

Due to the poor similarity measure, 
it affects the precision and recall.
May I know how to improve the precision , recall or the ranking method???

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a step forward and use language models for information retrieval. Use this [Tutorial from Stanford University](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/language-models-for-information-retrieval-1.html#ch:lmodels).

Comment: elaborate your answer though you are pointing OP to a good tutorial, you can give some introductory ideas and say why language models will be better for OP's task. otherwise you can write this as a comment.